# CSRF script dont work

Tags: php, html, csrf-protection

why wont this script protect my form against CSRF attacks? like i tried to add the demo form they had on the site nocsrf site and that worked perfectly. When I change the code of the csrf token nothing happends and it just process the information to the database on my currently form.

Here is my 
Form part, it is on the same page as the html form:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO contact (name, email, topic, `description`, IP, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['topic'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $config) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "takk.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

here is my html form part:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

<h4>Navn:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" size="32" required>

<h4>Email:</h4>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" size="32" required>


<h4>Kategori:</h4>
<select name="topic" class="form-control">
        <option value="Generelt" <?php if (!(strcmp("Generelt", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Generelle spørsmål</option>
        <option value="Problemer" <?php if (!(strcmp("Problemer", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Problemer</option>
        <option value="Klage" <?php if (!(strcmp("Klage", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Klage</option>
        <option value="Bugs" <?php if (!(strcmp("Bugs", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Bugs</option>
      </select>

<h4>Hva lurer du på?</h4>
      <textarea name="description" class="form-control" cols="50" rows="5" required></textarea>
<br />
      <button type="submit" class="blue-button" style="width:100%;">Send henvendelse</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
```

Nocsrf.php

```
<?php
/**
 * NoCSRF, an anti CSRF token generation/checking class.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Thibaut Despoulain <http://bkcore.com/blog/code/nocsrf-php-class.html>
 * Licensed under the MIT license <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php>
 *
 * @author Thibaut Despoulain <http://bkcore.com>
 * @version 1.0
 */
class NoCSRF
{
    protected static $doOriginCheck = false;
    /**
     * Check CSRF tokens match between session and $origin. 
     * Make sure you generated a token in the form before checking it.
     *
     * @param String $key The session and $origin key where to find the token.
     * @param Mixed $origin The object/associative array to retreive the token data from (usually $_POST).
     * @param Boolean $throwException (Facultative) TRUE to throw exception on check fail, FALSE or default to return false.
     * @param Integer $timespan (Facultative) Makes the token expire after $timespan seconds. (null = never)
     * @param Boolean $multiple (Facultative) Makes the token reusable and not one-time. (Useful for ajax-heavy requests).
     * 
     * @return Boolean Returns FALSE if a CSRF attack is detected, TRUE otherwise.
     */
    public static function check( $key, $origin, $throwException=false, $timespan=null, $multiple=false )
    {
        if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ] ) )
            if($throwException)
                throw new Exception( 'Missing CSRF session token.' );
            else
                return false;

        if ( !isset( $origin[ $key ] ) )
            if($throwException)
                throw new Exception( 'Missing CSRF form token.' );
            else
                return false;
        // Get valid token from session
        $hash = $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ];

        // Free up session token for one-time CSRF token usage.
        if(!$multiple)
            $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ] = null;
        // Origin checks
        if( self::$doOriginCheck && sha1( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) != substr( base64_decode( $hash ), 10, 40 ) )
        {
            if($throwException)
                throw new Exception( 'Form origin does not match token origin.' );
            else
                return false;
        }

        // Check if session token matches form token
        if ( $origin[ $key ] != $hash )
            if($throwException)
                throw new Exception( 'Invalid CSRF token.' );
            else
                return false;
        // Check for token expiration
        if ( $timespan != null && is_int( $timespan ) && intval( substr( base64_decode( $hash ), 0, 10 ) ) + $timespan < time() )
            if($throwException)
                throw new Exception( 'CSRF token has expired.' );
            else
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Adds extra useragent and remote_addr checks to CSRF protections.
     */
    public static function enableOriginCheck()
    {
        self::$doOriginCheck = true;
    }
    /**
     * CSRF token generation method. After generating the token, put it inside a hidden form field named $key.
     *
     * @param String $key The session key where the token will be stored. (Will also be the name of the hidden field name)
     * @return String The generated, base64 encoded token.
     */
    public static function generate( $key )
    {
        $extra = self::$doOriginCheck ? sha1( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) : '';
        // token generation (basically base64_encode any random complex string, time() is used for token expiration) 
        $token = base64_encode( time() . $extra . self::randomString( 32 ) );
        // store the one-time token in session
        $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ] = $token;
        return $token;
    }
    /**
     * Generates a random string of given $length.
     *
     * @param Integer $length The string length.
     * @return String The randomly generated string.
     */
    protected static function randomString( $length )
    {
        $seed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijqlmnopqrtsuvwxyz0123456789';
        $max = strlen( $seed ) - 1;
        $string = '';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i )
            $string .= $seed{intval( mt_rand( 0.0, $max ) )};
        return $string;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping the values and building your queries like that, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: I only see that you echo a variable called `$token` in your form, but where do you actually check it when handling the posted form?

Comment: Was not aware that i needed to verify the token, any ideas how i can solve this ?

Comment: Well, you have a method called `check()` in your `NoCSRF`-class. You could try using that? You could also check their examples (perhaps some documentation?) on how they are doing it. If you don't verify the token, it's not much of a protection since anyone can send in anything.

Comment: you should use magic CSRF library. this is easy to use.
https://github.com/ezyang/csrf-magic